# How do I deal with the warning Unknown escape sequence '\040' in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode, warnings

I have the following Warning popping up in a few of the Applescripts I'm running in a Cocoa application:

[http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/unknown-escape-sequence-error/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/unknown-escape-sequence-error)

I have tried everything I can think of to remove the error such as totally rewriting it, copying and pasting from another similar script that doesn't have the warning etc. but I can't get rid of it. Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong.

The raw code I'm using is:

```
NSString *theCellRefScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Numbers\"\n\
                                                tell document 1 \n\
                                                tell sheet \"%@\" \n\
                                                tell table \"%@\" \n\
                                                set value of cell \"%@\" to \%@\ \n\
                                                end tell \n\
                                                end tell \n\
                                                end tell \n\
                                                end tell ", theSheet, theTable, theCell, [theDistributionValues objectAtIndex:k]];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't open yourself up to this sort of problem in the first place.

Objective-C, like all modern C compilers, automatically concatenates string literals if they are seperated by whitespace.  Rather than your multi-line horror with its trailing slashes, use:

```
 NSString *theCellRefScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Numbers\"\n"
                                                "tell document 1\n"
                                                "tell sheet \"%@\ \n"
                                                "tell table \"%@\ \n"
                                                "set value of cell \"%@\" to \%@ \n"
                                                "end tell\n"
                                                "end tell\n"
                                                "end tell\n"
                                                "end tell", theSheet, theTable, theCell, [theDistributionValues objectAtIndex:k]];
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a trailing space on the end of a line, after the final backslash. It thinks you're trying to escape a space, not join lines.

edit: I'll even tell you how I knew, so you know for next time. From the error text, '040' is an octal number. Convert to decimal, 4 * 8 = 32, and ASCII 32 = space. A space is not a valid escape character. Some editors have a 'show whitespace' mode which'll show you tabs and spaces to help weed out issues like this.

Comment: Graham, I had already checked every line and there was no trailing space. The problem actually occured in the middle of a line rather than at the end.

Comment: Ah, OK. I figured it was a line end since the error was showing near the line end. ANyway, glad you figured it out! Those whitespace issues are nearly invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, there was a rogue space on the line starting set value of cell. The working version is:

```
set value of cell \"%@\" to \%@\\n\
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts because I really just couldn't see it. In my case it turned out to be rather simple: In my help text I had written that a certain option would escape all spaces - and I gave an example,

```
"\ "
```

Of course this became something like:

```
"\"\ \""
```

It's not visually obvious at all... but the backslash in the middle needs to be escaped, too:

```
"\"\\ \""
```

HTH